# grep first column uniq values

Tags: awk, grep

Two columns A and B: Column A have repeated ids and column B has different values for each corresponding  repeated value. I would like to read every uniq value from Column A with only the first hit from column B

File_B.txt

```
A 1
A 2
B 3
B 2
B 4
C 1
C 5
D 4
D 3
E 2
```

Output:

```
A 1
B 3
C 1
D 4
E 2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sort -k1,1 -u file
```

Sort file by first column and take first unique entry only.

Comment: Note that `sort -u` can return incorrect result in locales which have collating characters sort the same. Example `printf '%b\n%b\n' $'\U2460' $'\U2461' | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort -u`

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk '!($1 in a){a[$1];print}' <file
```

or:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' <file
```